# Favicon won't load

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the issue, but I had a similar issue about a year ago because the FAVICON was not the right dimensions. They are usually 15X15, 20X20, and 30X30. I hope that helps.

Comment: explain more plse!!